# Using local src in font face for Cambria

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser, font-face

As you know Mac systems support Cambria font in less than 33% cases. So I have to use font-face for it. I need a code to help the user's browser (Depending their systems) if they hadn't the font then download it.
So I wrote this pure css code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:Cambria;
    src:
    local('Cambria'), 
    url('../fonts/Cambria/Cambria.ttf');
}

body{
    font-family:Cambria, Georgia, serif;
}
```

It looks all right. But when I use this site (https://tools.pingdom.com) to check the problems, for chrome or firefox or other browser, this site monitors that I have a download for the ttf file. I think because I already have the font it should not download it and must read it as a local font.
What is the problem. Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: @Thariama I saw you have a perfect answer for same question. can you help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

The font might be downloaded because the font is unavailable on the system(OS). Depending on the OS, location of fonts on system might vary. You can easily check whether a particular font is available on the underlying system. See below link for checking installed fonts:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/22277/how-to-install-manage-and-delete-fonts-on-your-pc/

I tested a sample page using 'Cambria' font and verified that no request was fired from browser to download the font (as my system already has Cambria font installed).

A sample code can be found on below pen:

http://codepen.io/kaashan/pen/ygjjmb

```
@font-face {
    font-family:Cambria;
    src: local('Cambria'), url('../fonts/Cambria/Cambria.ttf');
}
```

You can open the browser dev tools and monitor what requests are fired(just change some text in HTML section). If you see a request for 'Cambria.ttf', it simply means that the particular font wasn't available for browser.

Since my system had 'Cambria' fonts, I had to modify local url to 'Cambria A' to see the request being fired.